# How to tell if the balls and urns are distinguishable?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If we have $m$ Urns and $n$ balls, then there are $4$ different ways to distribute the urns into balls, namely:

1. balls and urns are distinguishable,
2. balls are not distinguishable but the urns are,
3. balls are distinguishable but urns are not, and
4. neither the urns or balls are distinguishable.

Of course, for each of these cases we have a normal case, an injective case, a surjective case and a bijective case. For each of these cases, and sub-cases, there are equations that we can use to solve different questions. So we can turn problems such as "Distribute $7$ assistants into $4$ subjects, s.t. each subject has at least $1$ assistant." In this case, the assistants are the balls and the subjects are the urns, and since each subject has to have at least $1$ assistant, we know that this is a surjective case. However, how do if the balls and urns are distinguishable or not?

Comment: You have to read the question carefully.  It is an English question, not a mathematics one.  Once you have decided whether the balls are urns are distinguishable, it is then a mathematics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing unless it is specified in the problem. Distributing "balls into urns" is ambiguous and part of the problem is to make the parameters clear. If you want to learn more about the classification of the different problem types, though you already seem to have a grasp of the subtleties, you could look up the [Twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way). For example, Richard Stanley talks about it in [Enumerative Combinatorics - Volume I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107602629). This is still not a complete classification as there are many other parameters that can be imposed, such as upper bounds and lower bounds on the boxes other than just "at least one ball per box," whether it is possible to not use some of the balls, whether the ordering of the balls matter within boxes (look up [Lah numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number)), or maybe order only matters up to cyclicity (see [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)).

Answer (score 0):

In your example of $7$ balls and $4$ urns, the presumption would be that to find the probability you divide the number of cases where there is a requirement to have at least $1$ ball in each urn by the number of cases where there is no such requirement, presuming that each case is equally probable:

- balls and urns are distinguishable (i.e. physical reality): you can use [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) to say there are $\frac{4!}{0!}\, S_2(7,4) = 8400$ ways with at least $1$ ball in each urn and $4^7=16384$ ways in total
- balls are not distinguishable but the urns are: *[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))* will give you ${6 \choose 3}=20$ ways with at least $1$ ball in each urn and ${10 \choose 3}=120$ ways in total
- balls are distinguishable but the urns are not: you can again use Stirling numbers of the second kind to say there are $S_2(7,4) = 350$ ways with at least $1$ ball in each urn and $S_2(7,1)+S_2(7,2)+S_2(7,3)+S_2(7,4)=715$ ways in total
- neither the urns nor the balls are distinguishable: partitions of $7$ into *exactly* $4$ positive parts will give you $3$ ways with at least $1$ ball in each urn, and partitions of $7$ into *up to* $4$ positive parts will give you $11$ ways in total

These give you different probabilities of at least $1$ ball in each urn: $\frac{8400}{16384}\approx 0.5127$, $\frac{20}{120}\approx 0.1667$, $\frac{315}{750}\approx 0.4895$, $\frac{3}{11}\approx 0.2727$

I would regard the first as plausibly having equal probabilities for each outcome unless you have some special information about the structure of the exercise.  So if you plan to use an equal probability counting argument, I would suggest you work with distinguishable balls and distinguishable urns.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some subtlety here, and people who set such problems should take care to avoid ambiguity (or embrace it and ask for all answers). Because subject are usually distinguishable, such as number theory vs. analysis vs. probability, I would expect them to be distinguishable here. Because assistants are people, who generally are have names and unique personalities, I would expect the assistants to be distinguishable too. But if the assistants were distributed into four *groups* or *sets,* I would not expect to distinguish the sets or groups.

It seems a little subjective, however, doesn't it? It seems reasonable to me to ask questions in cases like this. "The assistants to be considered distinguishable, is that right?" "Are the subjects to be considered distinguishable too?"